# Add date to log file name in Logging Application Block

Tags: logging, enterprise-library, application-blocks

I'm using the Microsoft Logging Application Block (version 5 beta 2) and I'm trying to dynamically set the file name of a log file to the year month and day (and then write a new log file every day).  However, at runtime, the logger ignores any dynamic environment variables such as %date%, %time%, or %cd%. I can add static environment variables to the file name (such as %username%), but not dynamic environment variables.  Does anyone know how to get the rolling flat file trace listener to dynamically set the date in the log file name?

(this is what I was setting the File Name as:  Log_%date%.log)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave up on the Logging Application Block and switched to log4net.  Log4net lets me set the name of the log to today's date with a web.config setting.  I wrote an article on Code Project that shows how to get log4net working with the Policy Injection Application Block [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/LoggingDemo.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

@Robertc, I know this question has been marked but I think I have a trick that you can use for your next project : Use your own environment variable!

E.g. 
Before you make any call to the Logging Block

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MYDATE", "15/07/2010"); // << change the hardcoded date to get from DateTime
Debug.WriteLine (Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"c:\Log\Log_%MYDATE%.log"));
```

In your app.config, in the appropriate Rolling flat file trace listener

```
FileName=Log_%MYDATE%.log
```

**Note: This trick will only work if you restart your application daily.**