# Enterprise Library Logging

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

Log file names now support the use of environment variables. You can include environment variables such as `%WINDIR%, %TEMP%,` and `%USERPROFILE%` in the Filename property of the Flat File Trace Listener, Rolling Flat File Trace Listener, and XML Trace Listener.

```
<add name="Trace" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
fileName="Logs\trace_%DATE%.log" header="" footer="" formatter="Trace"
traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" />
```

Result filename - trace_.log, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Personally, I don't see a lot of value in having the date/time at which the log file was started as part of the file name.  I'd rather have the current file named something like "trace_current.log" and use the RollingFlatFileTraceListener to archive old files.  It automatically puts a timestamp in the filename of rolled files.

Comment: Thanks! RollingFlatFileTraceListener is the answer i'v been looking for

Answer (score 0):

`DATE` is a dynamic environment variable (i.e., one who's value can change during a session), and I don't think EL supports those.

See [Add date to log file name in Logging Application Block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647657/add-date-to-log-file-name-in-logging-application-block) for a possible solution, but it's not an ideal one.

Comment: It's really bad idea to create another variable, maybe i can add date value to filename in code?

Comment: As I say, it's not an ideal solution...!