# Change log file name during runtime - ent lib

Tags: enterprise-library

I have a WCF service that will serve multiple clients. I'm using ent lib for the logging.
I'd like to have a different log file for each client. is there a way to change the file name back and forth?
I found a few threads but they all talk about editing the config file during runtime.
ALso found this: [Enterprise Library Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804766/enterprise-library-logging) but it talks about environment variables. I will set the log name according to the client id.

Thanks
Avi

Comment: I guess another way to look at this would be to be able to use placeholders in the config. something like 
<add fileName="{myname}.txt".

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can have distinct categories linked to individually configured FlatFile or RollingFile tracelisteners for each client.

If filenames are unknown till runtime, consider using fluent API for configuration, like so:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363(PandP.50).aspx#fluent_api_logging

Comment: Categories are not good. Let's say I serve humans. every request comes from a person with an id. I want the session that served the person to write a log with the user id as the file name. every request will end up with a unique file name. there will never be 2 of the same name.

Hope it helps. Avi

Comment: Ok, have yoiu tried my other suggestion of programmatically configuring your tracelisteners?